# Regex to extract numbers and group them with thousands separator

Tags: java, regex, string, numbers

In my calculator app I have a string like this

`String input = "-.46sin(34)*23000.34(2^3"`

I want to add thousand separators to the numbers in the string
so that the output would be like :

`-.46sin(34)*23,000.34(2^3`

How can I achieve this with regex ? The language I work with is Java and float precision is 6

**Update:** 
final answer by Ulugbek Umirov in the comment is the correct answer
Regex : 
`(?<!\.\d{0,6})\d+?(?=(?:\d{3})+(?:\D|$))` 
Java Code : 
`String output = input.replaceAll("(?<!\\.\\d{0,6})\\d+?(?=(?:\\d{3})+(?:\\D|$))", "$0,");`

Comment: Do you have some code?

Comment: In general, I would advise to parse the numbers with a regex (`\d` comes in handy) and then format them with something else. If your app is a calculator, to evaluate expressions like that you'll have to parse and build an AST anyway.

Comment: @Paul Vargas  I dont think any code is needed. 
It's a general question... I intend to use String.replace(Target,Replacement) method of java
using regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following regex can give you the idea:

```
(?<!\d\.\d{0,6})\d+?(?=(?:\d{3})+(?:\D|$))
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Replace it with `$0,`

[Demo](http://fiddle.re/hpcta6)

Comment: Ulugbek Umirov 
There's just one thing ... when I use it with this test Case ".46sin(34)*23000.34+.5623(0.3333^3*1300000" 
float number .5623 also gets the comma.
is there a way to fix this ?

Comment: @9patchcoder Yes, I assume that there is always a digit before the dot. You can remove this assumption by using the following regex: `(?<!\.\d{0,6})\d+?(?=(?:\d{3})+(?:\D|$))`